# PHP form submission not working when disabling drag and drop on an HTML element

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to this website, please forgive me if I do something wrong. I've been looking for a solution on the internet all day, and I've found nothing that could solve my problem.

I've come here with an interesting issue. Here's the thing.

I've got a login "system" which works with MySQL. Now, the HTML part of the login form looks like this:

```
<form id="loginForm" method="POST" action="login.php">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Username:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="username" class="textInput" placeholder="Type here your username"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password:</td>
                                <td><input type="password" name="password" class="textInput" placeholder="Type here your password"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" class="Login" value="Log in"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><a ondragstart="return false;" href='register.php'>Don't have an account? Create one!</a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
```

I've disabled dragging link in the 'a' tag because I don't want users to be able to drag and drop the link in their browsers, being able to access the application through browser since this is a CEF app.

Now, when I use that code above that disables dragging I won't be able to log in.
Here's the PHP code:

```
<?php
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(empty(trim($_POST['username'])) || empty(trim($_POST['password'])))
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Alert.render('You must provide a valid username and password to log in.', 'Login Process');</script>";
    }else{
        $sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username='$username'";
        $result = $conn->query($sqlCode);
        $logincount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if($logincount > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    if($row['isBanned'] == 1)
                    {
                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Alert.render('This user is banned, thus you cannot log in.', 'Login Process');</script>";
                    }else{
                        if($username == $row['username'] && $password == $row['password'])
                        {
                            if($row['isAdmin'] == 1)
                            {
                                $isAdmin = true;
                                @$_SESSION['isAdmin'] = $isAdmin;
                            }
                            @$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                            $userid = $row['user_id'];
                            @$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
                            header('location:news.php');
                        }else{
                            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Alert.render('Your username or password is incorrect.', 'Login Process');</script>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>Alert.render('We are sorry, but the user does not exist.', 'Login Process');</script>";
            }
        }
    }
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

If I type incorrect credentials or don't type anything at all, it will show pop ups. Everything works fine until I provide correct credentials. In that case it won't let me in, just will reload the page. What have I done wrong? I've been trying to solve this issue, but it won't work. On the bright side, the script which disables dragging works, but it will make the login system not to.

I'm a beginner at PHP coding, I hope I'm not cringey. :)

Thank you for the answers in advance! :)

**Edit:** I don't think it's the @$_SESSION instead of $_SESSION because both work fine when there isn't that event in the 'a' tag.

Comment: Seems to me that you're typing ```@$_SESSION``` and it should be ```$_SESSION```

Comment: The @ is a thing I used to do all the time 500 years ago, it makes it not give a warning if undefined. When you have warnings on that is. And, IIRC of course.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your changes related to this fault.

Probably server settings were changed as well. Try to add in your php script by first line (after `<?php` of course):

```
session_start
```

do the same in `news.php` as well.